# Python modules "Processing", "Multiprocessing" and other concurrency modules: what are the differences?

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am starting to read up over possible ways to parallelise Python code.

DISCLAIMER. This is NOT a question about Multiprocessing vs Multithreading.

At this link https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/demos.html one finds references to several
concurrency packages for Python to avoid the GIL: https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/ParallelProgramming

-IPython1

-mpi4py

-parallel python

-Numba

There is also a multiprocessing package:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

And another one called processing:
https://pypi.org/project/processing/

First of all, it is not at all clear to me the difference between the latter two above; what is the difference in using between the multiprocessing module and the processing module?.

In general, I fail to understand the differences between those all -- which must be there, given some developers made the effort to create a mpi4py version for the MPI used in C++. I guess this is not just about the dualism between "threading" and "multiprocessing" approaches, where in one case the memory is shared while the other has each process with its own memory and interpreter, something more must be different between all of those different packages out there.

Thanks to all  of those who will dedicate time to answer this!

Comment: There are a litany of tutorials for what you are asking about as well as SO posts on the topic.  If you fail to understand something specific, let us know.

Comment: Sorry, but I actually checked on SO and around the web, I could not find any comparison between Multiprocessing and Processing modules, other than the other listed. If you have found some, please post me a link, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I would recommend to read carefully my question. It is NOT about multiprocessing vs multithreading, but Multiprocessing vs Processing packages plus all the other choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the last version of processing was [released in April of 2008](https://pypi.org/project/processing/#history) and multiprocessing was added in [Python 2.6 in October 2008.](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html)

processing was a library that was used before multiprocessing was distributed with Python.

As far as the specific difference between other modules designed for multiprocessing: The scipy page you linked says that "This is a subject for graduate courses in computer science, and I'm not going to address it here....there are some python tools you can use to implement the things you learn in that graduate course." While they admit that may be a bit of an exaggeration, independent study of multiprocessing in general will be required to discern the difference between these libraries, you should probably just stick to the built in multiprocessing module for your initial experiments while you learn how it works. One you're more comfortable with multiprocessing, you might want to check out the [pathos framework.](https://pypi.org/project/pathos/)

But here are the basics for the packages you mention:

Numba adds decorators that automatically compile functions to make them run faster, it isn't really a multiprocessing tool as much as a JIT compiling tool.

Parallel Python overcomes the GIL to utilize multiple cores or multiple computers, it's designed to be easy to use and to handle all the complex stuff behind the scenes.

MPI for Python is like Paralell Python with less emphasis on simplicity.

IPython is a toolkit with many features, including a shell and Jupyter kernel, it's also not really a multiprocessing tool.

Keep in mind that plenty of libraries/modules do the same thing, there doesn't need to be a reason more than one exists. Use whatever works for you.